# MySQL get specific date of last month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

I want to select all rows since `20th` last month.

I know I can select a date one month ago using `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`, but how can I set a specific day in that month?

Today is `March 28th`, I want to select all rows newer than `February 20th`.

Even if I could set the day directly, if the queried date was `31st` that wouldn't work for February, where instead it should select the last day of that month.

Note: 20th is just an example, the value is dynamically generated somewhere else in the code.

Some examples:

```
Day: 20th each month
Now: March 28th | Query: February 20th
Now: May 28th | Query: April 20th
```

```
Day: 31st each month
Now: March 28th | Query: February 28th // we select last day instead of 31st
Now: May 28th | Query: April 30th // we select last day instead of 31st
```

The full query would be something like `SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date > SET_DAY(20, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`.

So, what can I replace that `SET_DAY` with (that also works with shorter months)?

A pretty common use case for this are billing periods, where you want to select all data from within the current billing cycle.

Comment: `... WHERE date > DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-20')`

Comment: @Akina That seems like a good start. There is still the issue of that month not having the given day, right? Also, I am currently using DATETIME, converting to a DATE might lose some precision in changing (as it disregards hours).

Also, if the `-20` is inside a string, can it be used in a prepared statement?

Comment: ??? *There is still the issue of that month not having the given day, right?* I don't understand your words. *I am currently using DATETIME, converting to a DATE might lose some precision in changing (as it disregards hours)* You need to take into account both date and time? *if the -20 is inside a string, can it be used in a prepared statement* Of course. Do not forget to quote (double) single quote chars which wraps the literal.

Comment: @Akina If I set it to `30`, February 30th doesn't exist, it should instead use the last day of that month.

Comment: @Akina So if I have the 20 in a variable `$day`, how do I use it properly in the DATE_FORMAT?  Can I do `%Y-%m-:day` and then `bindValue(':day', 20, PDO::PARAM_INT)` ?

Comment: *Can I do %Y-%m-:day and then* I doubt.

Comment: The expression can be built, but it will be complex enough. We should take into account that needed day number may not exist in both current and previous month.

Comment: I would do `date(date_format(current_date - interval 1 month, '%Y-%m-01')) + interval ? - 1 day`

Comment: @ysth I also thought this would be a better solution, get first day of last month, add the desired days (eg. +20 or +31) and make sure to cap it to LASTDAY() of that month.

Comment: making sure $day is valid seems like a problem to solve client side?

Comment: @ysth That value is also stored in DB, so the main idea is that's a billing cycle that happens on $day each month, so the $day stored in DB could be 31. I would prefer to do everything in a MySQL query.

Comment: ah, ok.  added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a parameter in the client that is the target day number, and you want to validate it in the sql (making sure you come up with a day inside the previous month), not in the client, I would do:

```
least(
    date(date_format(current_date - interval 1 month, '%Y-%m-01')) + interval ? - 1 day,
    date(date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')) - interval 1 day
)
```

One caution: current_date will be the current date in the timezone of the connection, which is controlled by the client; I prefer to always be explicit if I know what timezone I want the day in, like:

```
date(convert_tz(utc_timestamp(), '+00:00', 'America/Los_Angeles'))
```

instead of just current_date (both places).

Comment: IS LEAST() different than MIN() ?  

LE: Found it: https://database.guide/min-vs-least-in-mysql-whats-the-difference/

tl;dr: MIN is an aggregation function over a column, LEAST operates only on the given arguments/primitves.

Comment: correct, min is the minimum value for an expression across multiple rows of data being grouped; least takes two (or more) expressions and returns the least of them; here we want the least of the calculated billing cycle date and the last day of the month (the first day of the current month - 1 day)

Comment: > and you want to validate it in the sql

It's not like that stored day itself is invalid, in some months it's valid, it's some it's not and the query should always return a correct date.

This seems to work as expected!

Comment: I just realized that there's another case. If the day is within this month. So if today is `20th` of April and the billing cycle is from `15th`, it should get it from `15th` this month instead of last month. It should only get from last month if it's larger than today.

Comment: I just realized my last comment makes this question almost completely different. I think adding `SELECT 
IF(DAY(current_date) >= ?...` should work.

Comment: so you want the current billing cycle?

Comment: Yes, more exactly the last payment date (which is always on the Xth of the month). It seems like the changes added in my answer work, but the query seems a bit too complex for this simple question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I believe this solves the problem

```
select now()
- interval 1 month
- interval(
   day(now())
   - least(
      20,
      day(last_day(now() - interval 1 month))
     )
  ) day
```

Comment: You do not take into account that today's day number may not exist in previous month. And you'll obtain not 20th but 17..19th. Calculate the output if NOW() is March, 31...

Comment: @nicael Thanks! Does it work when now it's 30th and last month only has 28th days? Or when the requsted date is "30th last month", but because last month is shorter, it should return "28 Feb" instead of "30th Feb"?

Comment: I see, I'll address that @Akina (currently coming up with the solution)

Comment: @Akina seems I have nailed that

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that my question didn't include all cases. If the last billing date is within this month, it should count the 20th of this month (not previous one).

Based on @ysth answer, I added an IF to select 20th of this month (if we are passed it), otherwise of previous month:

```
IF(DAY(current_date) >= 20, 
   date(date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')) + interval 20 - 1 day,
    least(
        date(date_format(current_date - interval 1 month, '%Y-%m-01')) + interval 20 - 1 day,
        date(date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')) - interval 1 day
    )
);
```